# python WeightConverter returns None after recursive call

Tags: python, if-statement, return

This is a basic program which converts the user's `givenWeight` into another unit. Something is going wrong in the `else` statement, where after the user gives an invalid value, the program asks for the value again, but returns `None` insead of the expected result.

```
givenWeight = int(input("Weight? "))  
unit = input("lbs or kgs? ") 
converted = 0


def convertWeight(weight, unit):
    if unit == "lbs":
        converted = f"{weight * 0.454} kgs"
        return converted
    elif unit == "kgs":
        converted = f"{weight * 2.205} lbs"
        return converted
    else:
        print("Invalid unit")
        unit = input("lbs or kgs? ") 
        convertWeight(givenWeight, unit) # recalls function to convert weight


output = convertWeight(givenWeight, unit)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive call to convertWeight after your else statement is only returning the string value to that point in the code. Also note that your global variable converted is both unnecessary and not the same object as the variable in the function. Why not use something simple.

```
def convertWeight(weight, unit):
    while True:
        if unit == "lbs":
            converted = f"{weight * 0.454} kgs"
            return converted
        elif unit == "kgs":
            converted = f"{weight * 2.205} lbs"
            return converted
        else:
             print("Invalid unit")
             unit = input("lbs or kgs? ")
```

Comment: Imma try this code, thanks for the help tho

Comment: Hey, it works, i'd be interested in knowing exactly what i did wrong tho, about the recursion thing, and why you added a while true

Comment: I used an earlier if else statement loop for this, and it would give me the same value twice if the unit entered in the first try was correct

Comment: Oh, i understood thanks, the while true keeps executing the code while it is not satisfied, and the return statement automatically stops the code, since thats what return does

Comment: You've got it now. The problem with your recursion approach was the function call after ELSE produced a string then did nothing with it; you probably thought the string would be returned outside the function. May I suggest you check out https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit which allows you to step through Python code to watch what is happening; there are also some good basic code samples.

Comment: sure thanks, i will see that